# Merge new branch with uncorrelated history into repository subdirectory using Git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

There are 2 branches in a repository: master and my_branch. my_branch is newly pushed branch with contents from another repository and uncorrelated history. I would like to merge my_branch into master, however:

```
git checkout master
git merge master my_branch
```

would merge them on the root level which is not what I want.

I would like to merge the root directory contents of my_branch with subdirectory of the root directory of master.

Would anyone be able to advise me on how to proceed on this?

Comment: Idea: Switch to my_branch and move everything into subdirectory (and add-and-commit); now switch to master and merge my_branch.

Comment: Indeed this is the way to go, I did try it (encapsulate in a new subdirectory) before asking, but could not succeed to checkout my_branch in order to copy contents into new folder prior to merge. It turns out that $git pull was necessary before calling $git checkout my_branch. The rest of the process is as expected, $git merge master my_branch --allow-unrelated-histories

Comment: Feel free to give your solution as an answer to your own question! Might help someone.